# Expamples of municipal decisions register published as open data

Tags: government, city

can anybody give me any examples of municipal decisions register (eg. planned road closures, approval of private use of public spaces, sanctions issued to citizens for not obeying municipal regulations, list of municipal regulations...).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a preference on nation?

In the United States:

- Eminent Domain: You need the municipality's record of minutes, usually this can be found on the local website depending on your target state's transparency rules ([City of Ocoee Planning Agenda & Minutes](http://www.ocoee.org/745/Agenda-Center)).
- Planned road closures are not made as part of a municipal decision, it is a direct result of roadway decisions; traffic engineering would come up with a Maintenance of Operational Traffic; which includes roadway closures and other actions.
- Sanctions for failure to comply with municipal regulations would be found in the code violations department ([Hillsborough County has a searchable list](https://webapps.hillsboroughcounty.org/hcce/resources/onlineservices/enforcement/home.cfm)), but most of these would require going down to the municipality to do an information request.
- List of Municipal Regulations is something that varies wildly from city to city, you can find them listed on [each](http://www.hillsboroughcounty.org/index.aspx?NID=267) [municipality's](https://www.municode.com/library/fl/ocoee/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CH108MISTCO), [website](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/ah/supp_info/rules_and_ordinances.html); but there is no particular comparison checklist.